# Get distinct rows from table A which are different columns value in table B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL server, I have the following tables (they are simplified):

Table A:

```
ID| NAME | ID_STATUS | STATUS
--------------------------------
1 | One  | 1         | Confirmed 
2 | Two  | 2         | Pending 
3 | Three| 0         | Deleted 
4 | Four | 1         | Confirmed
```

Table B (Is a Detailed from A):

```
ID (same from A) | NAME | ID_STATUS | STATUS
-----------------------------------------------
1                | One  | 1         | Confirmed
1                | One  | 1         | Confirmed
2                | Two  | 2         | Pending
3                | Three| 2         | Pending
3                | Three| 2         | Pending
4                | Four | 2         | Pending
```

I need get distinct rows of (ID, NAME, ID_STATUS, STATUS) from A, which have (ID_STATUS, STATUS) different from B

Expected result:

```
ID | NAME | ID_STATUS | STATUS
---------------------------------
3  | Three| 0         | Deleted
4  | Four | 1         | Confirmed
```

I'm trying by a LEFT OUTER JOIN without success… (return 0 results)

```
select A.ID, A.NAME, A.ID_STATUS, A.STATUS from A left outer join B
   on A.ID = B.ID
   where
      A.ID_STATUS != B.ID_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.ID, A.NAME, A.ID_STATUS, A.STATUS 
from A 
left outer join B
      on A.ID        = B.ID 
     and A.ID_STATUS = B.ID_STATUS
where b.ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

select A.ID, A.NAME, A.ID_STATUS, A.Acol  from A  left outer join B on A.ID = B.ID and A.ID_STATUS = B.ID_STATUS where B.ID is null;